# Handling error message of 'undefined' in javascript

Tags: javascript

As I can see in almost case, javascript would throw message `undefined` or `x is not defined`, etc...

Here is some:

```
var i;
var j = i;
alert(j); // undefined

var xyz;
alert(xyz); // undefined
```

`undefined`? No, it's defined without a default value. So, the error message should be:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
>
> Use of unassigned local variable 'xyz'

The error message of

```
alert(xyz); // Uncaught ReferenceError: xyz is not defined

// or

alert(xyz === undefined); // Uncaught ReferenceError: xyz is not defined
```

should become

> The name 'xyz' does not exist in the current context

And the last:

```
alert(typeof(xyz) === 'undefined'); // true
```

So, the problem is: you want to get the type of `nothing`??? If something is-a `thing` (not `nothing`), the type should be an attribute of that. You can assign it after declaring, and only.

My question: how is my idea to handle that error messages?

p/s: I come from C# :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking here, but it seems that you want to have [a discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) about redesigning a fundamental part of the JavaScript language. This isn't the right place for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two concepts at play here:

- An identifier that is not defined (completely undeclared, doesn't exist in the current scope at all)
- An identifier that is defined (is declared, is in scope) that contains the *value* `undefined`

The short answer is: If you want to see if an identifier is currently in scope which may or may not be in scope, do this:

```js
if (typeof xyz === "undefined") {
    // Either the identifier isn't in scope, or it's in scope and has
    // the value undefined
}
```

`typeof xyz` will never throw an error, even if `xyz` is completely undeclared. This is (as you've found) different from `xyz === undefined`, which will throw a `ReferenceError` if `xyz` is a completely undeclared identifier.

> No, it's defined without a default value. So, the error message should be:
>
> ```
> Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
> ```
>
> ```
> Use of unassigned local variable 'xyz'
> ```

JavaScript has no concept of an unassigned variable. When a variable is created, it is automatically assigned the value `undefined`.

Comment: My mistake is `without a default value`, and the correct: the default value is `undefined`. Many thanks!